# Displaying html link data into arrays then append to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html, append

Im trying to retrieve my data, split it using data.split then

display my data into span,

data is located at http://www.examplewebsite.com/7.html which should contain a text on body similar to this "19,1,82,999,18,128,Rezonate - Monstercat 016 - Expedition - Canvas"

JavaScript

```
var data =$('http://www.examplewebsite.com/7.html').text();
alert(data); // just to check the value of data but that doesn't seem to be the value I'm looking for
var arr = data.split(',');
$("#display").append("<span>The Current Listeners is " + arr[0] + "</span></br><span>The Current Song is " + arr[6] + "</span></br>" );
```

Html

```
<div id="display"></div>
```

Any idea why it doesn't read the contents of the html ?

Comment: You're trying to do what now? Just pasting a link to a cross domain website inside jQuery doesn't really work.

Comment: Then how do i retrieve the text that is in the link for this case?

Comment: If it's cross domain and violates the same origin policy, you probably don't ?

Comment: To clear things up, I'm just trying to retrieve data from my radio server (shout cast on WHMSonic) to display the current listeners and current song and display it on my site.

I used to get the data via php but somehow after a few months it stopped working. So I'm just finding another way.